# Using Auth0 as external identity provider for Keycloak. How do I configure Auth0? Where would I obtain this information?

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying to configure Auth0 as an external identity provider for Keycloak. Although I believe I can configure it on Keycloak's side, I'm not sure about Auth0:

[image: Auth0 SAML config]

I'm not sure what I'd put in the Application callback URL and in the settings JSON. More importantly, I don't know where to find documentation or information on what URLs would be put here.

Any guidance and direction would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_identity_broker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use SAML, you can add Auth0 as a SAML identity provider to Keycloak first. Once you have done that, click on the `SAML 2.0 Service Provider Metadata` link as shown.

[image: SAML Identity Provider configuration]

You will see metadata similar to this:

```xml
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" entityID="http://localhost:8080/realms/test-realm" ID="ID_a03a6c5c-d075-40ec-a913-748ba3618837">
  <md:SPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="false">
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://localhost:8080/realms/test-realm/broker/saml/endpoint"/>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://localhost:8080/realms/test-realm/broker/saml/endpoint" isDefault="true" index="1"/>
  </md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

You will need the `Location` from the `AssertionConsumerService` element and add this to your Auth0 configuration as callback URL.

The URL has a pattern like `http://<host>:<port>/<context>/realms/<realmname>/broker/<identityprovider_alias>/endpoint`
The `/<context>` is generally `/auth`, but may be different or even missing depending on your configuration/version.